# ChronicleQueue - Unable to cleanup older CQ4 files

Tags: chronicle-queue

I am using CronicleQueue and I have only one writer/reader.  Wanted to cleanup as soon as the reader is done with a CQ4 file.  The following code wasn't able to remove the file, is the file reference still held by CQ during onReleased() event?

```
public class ChronicleFactory {
public SingleChronicleQueue createChronicle(String instance, String persistenceDir, RollCycles rollCycles) {
    SingleChronicleQueue chronicle = null;

    String thisInstance = instance;
    try {
    chronicle = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(persistenceDir).rollCycle(rollCycles).storeFileListener(new StoreFileListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReleased(int i, File file) {
        String currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy??-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        System.out.println(instance + "> " + currentTime + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " onReleased called for file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " for cycle: " + i);
        if(instance.equals("Reader")) {
            System.out.println("Removing previous CQ file: " + file.getName() + ", deleted? " + file.delete());  //==> Not able to delete the file !!!
        }
        }
    .....
```

Comment: usually the delete should work, is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is an optimal solution, please let me know if there is a cleaner way, but the following works [except it will have to loop few times before deleting, as the file is actually released after few milliseconds it seems, i see "file is closed" printed few time before the actual delete happens)

```
                @Override
            public void onAcquired(int cycle, File file) {
                String currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy‌​-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
                System.out.println(instance + "> " + currentTime + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " onAcquired called for file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " for cycle: " + cycle);
                if(prevCycleFile != null && instance.equals("Reader")) {
                    System.out.println(">>> Trying to remove: " + prevCycleFile);
                    boolean bDelete;
                    while((bDelete=prevCycleFile.delete())==false) {

                        System.out.println(">>> file is closed");    
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(">>> Removing previous CQ file: " + prevCycleFile.getAbsolutePath() + ", deleted? " + bDelete);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonable to expect a small delay between the Queue reporting that a file is released, and the OS actually detecting/acting upon it.

The `StoreFileListener` is invoked on the same thread that is reading or writing to the queue, so you will incur latency while the `while` loop is executing. You'll get better results by handing off the work of closing files to another thread (e.g. via a `j.u.c.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`).